# Two edit links on the blog's post-meta line in single-post view

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog

While obviously these links are only available to those with sufficient privileges on the blog;

[image: BlogOverflow post screenshot]

I suspect the first Edit is a stray, because the trailing " | Edit" looks much better. Especially considering the otherwise-leading date information on this line.

Comment: I only see one link. http://i.imgur.com/nJxmX.png

Comment: Aaand, I'm silly. It's there if you actually click on a post. http://i.imgur.com/OaGgu.png

Comment: But, you pointed out that I missed a fairly important detail. Single-post view. Updated title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out.  I just deployed a fix.

Comment: I can't believe I never accepted this. I guess I get to thank [Community ♦](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) for bumping it!